# Accessing variables from one function to another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

To start, here's a [small project](https://jackreacher2.github.io/PokemonFacts/) I made that throws a new fact every time the user presses the `New Fact` button. Source code available [here](https://github.com/jackReacher2/PokemonFacts/tree/gh-pages). Then I made a Twitter button to tweet **that** quote.

As you can see in main.js file, there's a variable called quotes which is an array of 40 quotes (snipped in the code below).

```
// var quotes defined above, an array of 40 quotes

$(".quoter").click(function() {

        // To generate a random number
        function randomRange(myMin, myMax) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (myMax - myMin + 1) + myMin); 
        }

        i = randomRange(0, 40);
        //Using the random number generated above to fetch a quote  
        $(".lead").text(quotes[i]);  

        var uriLink = encodeURIComponent(quotes[i]);

        $(".tweeter").click(function(){ 
            window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+uriLink+, "_blank");
        });
    });
```

Whenever the user clicks the Tweet button, it opens up multiple twitter tabs for each `i`. I want the tab to be opened for the current quote only. I tried keeping the two functions separate, and not nested but then `quotes[i]` becomes inaccessible resulting in `undefined`.

Comment: what is the specific problem and what is your question?

Comment: @charlietfl I want only one tweet tab to open which contains the current fact whenever the user presses the tweet button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're storing the text that you're URI-encoding in the `.lead` element, here's one way you can separate the functions:

```
$(".quoter").click(function() {
  function randomRange(myMin, myMax) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (myMax - myMin + 1) + myMin);
  }

  i = randomRange(0, 40);

  $(".lead").text(quotes[i]);
});

$(".tweeter").click(function() {
  var uriLink = encodeURIComponent($(".lead").text());
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + uriLink + , "_blank");
});
```

Comment: I tried that too, but that will give me just one quote, the initial one. It won't update as I iterate.

Comment: @Hyperbola Are you sure? The way it's written here, it will get the current text of the `.lead` element each time `.tweeter` is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I had tried the same thing but don't know why it didn't work out then. Thanks again!